# Does Crossmint work with Hashlips contracts?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, nft, crossmint

I would like to launch an NFT collection using the Hashlips NFT contract and add credit card payments with Crossmint. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Hashlips has ERC-721 and 1155 contracts that Crossmint supports

There's a guide here: https://docs.crossmint.io/recipes/adding-crossmint-button-to-your-website-ethereumpolygon

Comment: I would recommend putting the relevant parts of the guide in the question, as to avoid [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)